# how to use winpcap to send EAPOL packets on windows 7 with wireless card?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, 802.1x, winpcap

I want to implement a 802.1X wireless client on Windows 7 using PEAP/MSCHAPv2. The 802.1X protocol is a data link layer protocol, it uses the EAPOL protocol to encapsulate the packets. I use the WinPcap to send and receive the EAPOL packets, however I fail to do it with the wireless NIC. It can work fine to send the EAPOL packets use wired NIC. It can also work fine to send the EAPOL packets on Windows XP using wireless NIC. So what's wrong with it on Windows 7?

Comment: Um, are you aware that [WinPCap FAQ (Question 16)](http://www.winpcap.org/misc/faq.htm) states that wireless NICs aren't supported?

Comment: I take an experiment : a windows 7 PC and a windows XP PC are both connecting to a same SSID,then i send EAPOL packets use WinPcap on windows 7 with the wireless NIC to the windows XP PC . It works fine. However , when i associate with a AP , it cannot send the EAPOL packets use the winpcap.